# 1D array to 2D array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So in my javascript I have a huge 1D array and I want to convert it into a 2D array. This is what I have so far, but doesn't seem to work.

```
    var arrLines = strRawContents.split(",");
    var array2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            array2[i][j] = arrLines[(j * 98) + i];
        }
    }
    return arrLines
    }
```

This is what I currently have, where I'm trying to make 98 rows and in each row, there is 5 columns. My goal is complicated. If my 1D array were to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and so on], My 2D array at [0][0] should be 1, at [0][1] should be 2 and so on until [0][7] would be 8, then [1][0] would be 9, [1][1] would be 10 and so forth.

Comment: Oh It's suppose to be returning array2 o.o. So yah ignore that/

Comment: There's no *2D* or *associated array* in javascript as we have in PHP etc. Instead you use object. Just update line 2 to `var array2 = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every outer loop, create an array. In the inner loop, push contents into it, at the end of the outer loop, push that newly created array into the final 2-d array.

```
var arrLines = strRawContents.split(",");
var array2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    arr.push(arrLines[(i * 5) + j]);
  }
  array2.push(arr);
}
return arr2;
```

Some mistakes in your original code:

1. You need to initialize your `array2` to be an empty array.
2. There's no `int` keyword in JavaScript. Use `var` or `let` (`let` is preferred but not all browsers support it yet.
3. The formula should be `(i * 5) + j` not `(j * 98) + i`.
4. The return value should be `array2`.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. But for the 2D variable I have, I want the first array for example, (0) to be the row, then the next 6 items will be the column. And then it repeats with the 7th array being the next row and then 6 items after that being its column. Is there a way to do this, I would very appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment here. Could you update your question to illustrate the intended result with an example?

Comment: Please state the starting value for `strRawContents` and how the final 2-d array should look like. Sorry your comments are not very clear.

Comment: So for example if my 1D array were to be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 so on] My 2D array would be like so, [0][0] would be 1, [0][1] would be 2, so on till [0][7] would be 8. Then [1][0] would be 9, [1][1] would be 10. Hopefully this clears it up, just realized this seems very complicated.

Comment: I realized my answer does that currently, just that there are 98 rows of 5 elements each, which you specified in the question. Is it not working for you?

Comment: For some reason, it seems to skip some of the elements in the 1D array. The first line works perfectly, but for some reason, it skips a good chunk of info in the 1D array. Previously mentioning the example above, [0][7] would be 8, but then all of a sudden [1][0] would not be 9, but instead it goes up to 78 for example.